# Construct a symmetric confidence interval for the acceleration coefficient

Tags: numpy, math, scipy, statistics

A machine model is tested in the factory to check the acceleration coefficient. The experiment selects n machines of this model and measures the distance traveled by the machine in 38 seconds. It is assumed that path measurement errors are independently equally distributed and have a distribution of 1/2 - exp(1). Construct a symmetric confidence interval for the acceleration coefficient.
Input data: Two input values. The first is the confidence level, a number between 0 and 1. The second is a one-dimensional array numpy.ndarray of measurements in the path (in meters) of one model.
Returned value: A tuple or a list of two values equal to the left and right boundaries of the confidence interval.
I solved the problem this way:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

def solution(p: float, x: np.array) -> tuple:

    x_bar = np.mean(x)
    s = np.std(x, ddof=1)
    z = norm.ppf(1 - (1 - p)/2)
    lower = x_bar - z * s / np.sqrt(len(x))
    upper = x_bar + z * s / np.sqrt(len(x))
    t = 38
    v = x.mean() / t
    a = 2 * v / t
    lower_a = 2 * lower / t
    upper_a = 2 * upper / t
    return lower_a, upper_a
```

But the length of the interval turns out to be long. How do I solve the problem so that it fits the conditions below.
[image]

Comment: Alternatively, an asymptotic confidence interval can be constructed, but it will not be as accurate

Comment: Without being able to reproduce your problem with a sample data input and seeing how exactly the current result differs from your desired result, it will be difficult to help you. Your question seems to be more conceptual in nature, rather than about the programming implementation, so it seems better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It also seems like you need to actually explain what an "acceleration coefficient" is.

Comment: The acceleration factor is the same as the acceleration "a". I remember we studied this in school :)